# calculate joint hypothesis in R software

Tags: r

After running regression model in R software I have received the following output below. How can I Test the joint hypothesis that race does not affect wages? 
my variables are black, experience, hispanic, marriage, school and union.

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.775597   0.261259   2.969  0.00312 ** ,
P1$BLACK    -0.198431   0.060997  -3.253  0.00121 ** 
P1$EXPER    -0.001914   0.013785  -0.139  0.88965    
P1$HISP      0.042725   0.052982   0.806  0.42036    
P1$MAR       0.091047   0.038872   2.342  0.01953 *  
P1$SCHOOL    0.088346   0.013207   6.689 5.63e-11 ***
P1$UNION     0.117368   0.042941   2.733  0.00648 **
```

Comment: `anova(your_model)`? Can't help you without a reproducible example, unfortunately. You might have to reshape your data to have an `ethnicity` variable instead of separate variables.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ken. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. You'll get help faster if we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm able to get the results for joint probability in stata by running gen HB=black+hisp, but having difficulty to get the syntax that can calculate the joint hypothesis in R

Answer (score 0):

For testing of joint hypothesis ,you have to use `t-value` and `p-value`.
Here, `p-value` (BLACK) is `0.00121 < 0.05` i.e joint hypothesis that `race does not depends on wages` is rejected.
Since, we use `p-value` for individual testing and it is showing that variable `BLACK`; referring to race is statistically significant to explain wages.
In this way you can test your joint hypothesis.